# How to update the PATH for all jobs in an ADO pipeline

Tags: azure, path, yaml, pipeline, ado

I want to add to the path of all jobs.
I cant seem to figure out how to do that.
I can add to the path with a simple `export PATH=$PATH:/my/path`. This is really boiler plate though, because I need to add it to every job's script running the test. This also seems clunky having to export vars.

Is there an easy way to update the PATH to all jobs? Maybe in a pipeline template file?
I do want to do this via yaml files.